# Efficiency problem retrieving records on MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

For a college class I have, my group is modeling a database of a shopping list application.
On this database we have a table called "product", this table has all the products that a user can choose to put on their list. If the user doesn't find the product they wanted they can create a new one.
For this reason, on the "product" table we have a column called "client_id" that can be null. If the "client_id" column is null it means it was inserted by the developers and it should be showed to everyone, if it isn't null then a specific user put the product there and only that user should be able to see it.

Our teacher have said that this doesn't work very well as the application grows. He said that if we had a large amount of users and they decided to insert new products then the selection of products would take way too long (because it would have to filter if the client_id column is null or has the client id and the amount of registers would also be large).

So as we are running out of time we would like to know if there's something we can do in order to get rid of this problem

(I'm not a native speaker so please forgive any language mistakes)

[image: the tables "produto" (product) and "cliente" (client), both are in portuguese but I think they are understandable for what I've asked]

Comment: MySQL doesn't do `OR` queries very efficiently. The solution is to do two queries, one for `cliente_id IS NULL` and another for `cliente_id = :client`, and combine them with `UNION ALL`.

Comment: Thank you very much, I really appreciate your solution!  Just a quick question though, would you say that this solution would be quick even if the table had a large amount of records?

Comment: Yes, since there's an index on the foreign key.

Comment: @Barmar I think recently Oracle implemented the "Index Skip Scan" (or similar name) in MySQL, that was imported from Oracle DB. This could resolve `OR`s predicates much more efficiently.